# Access to internal classes from another project

Tags: c#, internal

I'm wondering if it's possible to access internal class variables from other project in c#. I know that is impossible in regular use, I explain it below.

I have one project (P1 [class library]) containing those classes...

```
internal class Settings
{
    public static long size {get;set;}

    public static DoSomethingInternalOnly()
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {

    }
}
```

... and another one (P2) containing:

```
public class Program
{
    public static Main()
    {
        //P1.CopyOfSettings.size = 2048; ???
    }
}
```

In Settings class I store internal variables (and methods) for app which cannot be visible from other projects. But those settings need to be passed somehow from P2 to P1 so I need second class "Settings2" in P2 containing the same variables (variables only!) as "Settings" with public keyword.

I feel that creating several classes containing the same variables is a waste of time and makes code unreadable. Is there better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Comment: **Passed** is the word. How exactly you want `Settings` to be passed? If they are serialized by `Program1`, then maybe you can deserialize them in `Program2`? Both projects can share definition class for settings only (methods are exclusive for `Program1` then).

Comment: _I feel that creating several classes containing the same variables is a waste of time and makes code unreadable. Is there better way to accomplish this?_ So create a separate class lib to share common classes.

Comment: This seems quite odd to me. If a class or member is `internal` it´s ment to be used only within a given assembly. If you need access from outside the assembly make the class public.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I want to create a lightweight assembly of "core" functionality for my Console Apps; then a heavier full-featured assembly to handle additional Web-Related features that will require Referencing Larger System.Web Assemblies.  I want my Web Assembly to have access to whatever is in my Core Assembly, but I do not want anyone else to use Parts of these Assemblies that were not meant for direct Public consumption.  This is one reason why marking everything as Public is a bad idea, and why they gave us the `InternalsVisibleTo` Attribute.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and provide the name of a specific assembly that can see the `internal` types in your assembly.

That being said.. I think you are bordering on over-designing this. If the `Settings` class belongs only to Assembly A... don't put it in Assembly B... put it in Assembly A.

Comment: I have a shared project which according to documentation compiles the units into the same assembly. I would have expected internal to be allowed but am getting the error. Has anyone tried internal with a shared project (i.e.not a separate assembly but still get error)

Comment: There are specific situations where "generally" internal classes of a project must be accessed by specific points of other projects. For example this happens for unit-tests and a composition root in the context of dependency injection.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is, using InternalsVisibleTo, but I would only recommend doing this for Unit Test projects.

Otherwise, you should extract a common interface, make it public and put it in a separate assembly that can be references by both projects.

You could make all the properties of the interface read-only so that the consumer cannot change them.

Answer (score 2):

### Project containing the internal

In the .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyName>CompanyName.ProjectName</AssemblyName>
  <RootNamespace>CompanyName.ProjectName</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>CompanyName.ProjectNameTest</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

### Project wishing to access the internal

In the .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyName>CompanyName.ProjectNameTest</AssemblyName>
  <RootNamespace>CompanyName.ProjectNameTest</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

That is the point of `internal` modifier - to not allow this. Either change it to public or use some kind of proxy class to expose the functionality you need to the outer world.

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic, did I ever said the opposite? It's not a good approach in my opinion though, what if you'll need to use it later in more assemblies? Will you keep adding more attributes to accommodate the needs? Internal modifier was introduced to prevent access from outside and this attribute is just an excuse for lazy people who can't create a proper architecture for their software. As Matthew Watson said, it shouldn't be used outside unit testing and similar situations...

Comment: Of course and I can't be against this idea. I disagree with your answer for this question, that's all.