# How to work with a main project and sub-projects in visual studio using namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm not familiar with namespaces and can't make it to work in visual studio 2017 community.
I created a solution with a empty project, I added a class file in that project:

```
namespace MainProject
{
   class MainClass
   {
      //some methods
   }
}
```

then I added a empty project to the solution and also added a class file:

```
namespace MainProject.SubProject
{
   class SubClass
   {
      MainClass var;
      public SubClass()
      {
         var=new MainClass();
      }
   }
}
```

The solution structure is like that:

```
Solution
|
|__MainProject
|  |__MainClass.cs
|
|__SubProject
   |__SubClass.cs
```

But I receive the error: error CS0246: `The type or namespace name 'MainClass' could not be found`
I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: When the files are in different project, you need to add a reference between the projects. The sub-project _(that use the main-project)_ should have a reference in the `References` to the main-project.

Comment: yes, this is it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have two problems (unless you've glossed over referencing MainProject from SubProject).

1) Classes are `internal` by default. For it to be seen by another project, it either needs to be [intentionally exposed to that other project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527332/access-to-internal-classes-from-another-project) or, more commonly, marked as `public`:

```
public class MainClass
{
    //some methods
}
```

2) You haven't added a reference to your `MainProject` project from `SubProject`, so even if you fix #1, you'll still have a problem.

You can add a reference by right-clicking the `SubProject` in Solution Explorer, selecting References (or Dependencies if you're working with .NET Core/Standard), selecting Add Reference, and then selecting your `MainProject` from the Projects list.

Comment: The `public` miss was just an oversight, ok for the reference, it works. Thanks.