# Right organization of dependencies between projects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks, dependencies

Good afternoon. How should I organize the following structure using C#, the .NET platform, and Visual Studio projects?

The solution should contains several projects (dll or winmd as result). `FrameworkB` and `FrameworkC` depend on `FrameworkA`. `ClassA` from `FrameworkA`, `ClassD` from `FrameworkB`, and `ClassF` from `FrameworkC` are public and visible to framework users; other classes are not accessible to them (there is no possibility to create objects or call a methods). In this case, from `ClassE` and `ClassG` we should be able to use the methods from `ClassB` and `ClassC`.

So:

- `FrameworkA`, `FrameworkB`, and `FrameworkC` should be a different `.dll` or `.winmd` files (But `B` and `C` depend on `A`).
- `ClassB`, `ClassC`, `ClassE`, and `ClassG` should be private to framework end-users, but `B` and `C` should be visible and used by `E` and `G`.

```
Solution
    FrameworkA
        ClassA
        ClassB
        ClassC
    FrameworkB
        ClassD
        ClassE
    FrameworkC
        ClassF
        ClassG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527377/2077697), you could use an InternalsVisibleTo attribute and use Internal access modifier on classes B and C.

That way, classes from the first assembly can be used by other two, but not by client written software.